# how to start HAXM in android studio

Tags: android

When i try to develop android app using android studio I faced the problem "**your computer does not support intel virtualization technology**" .
Then I tried to enable `vt- x in BIOS` setting.
But my processor(`intel B950`) does not have **intel virtualization technology**.
So how can I start **Haxm**?

Answer (score 0):

Your processor (intel B950) does not support virtualization technology. Hence you are out of luck to gain hardware acceleration for a speedy emulator. However you still should be able to run **arm** targeted emulators, though in slow speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use HAXM without Intel's virtualization technology support by your BIOS and CPU.

Answer (score 0):

There are some non-HAXM emulators. Genymotion is suggested a lot.